# Как добавить ключ в массив при переборке foreach

Tags: php

[Есть массив](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/5957f5210c327204ef06b387adaf25ca348a2318):

```
$test = [
    0 => [
        'id' => 1,
        'name' => 'test'
    ],
    1 => [
        'id' => 2,
        'name' => 'test'
    ]
];
```

И простая переборка `foreach` с попыткой добавить в массив ключ со значением

```
foreach($test as $t) {
    $t['test'] = 'add';
}
```

Почему таким образом в массив не добавляется ключ?
Рабочий вариант найден, просто интересно знать почему первый вариант не работает

```
foreach($test as $key => $t) {
    $test[$key]['test'] = 'add';
}
```

Comment: Ваш последний вариант и ответ от Manitikyl работают, потому что заполняется сам массив. Ваш первый вариант не работает, потому что заполняется элемент массива, но при этом не обновляется сам массив исходный. Без ключа или передаче по ссылке это не сработает. Но с ссылками нужно быть осторожными, а то можно исходник затереть))

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
foreach($test as $t) {
    $t['test'] = 'add';
}
```

Потому что тут при переборе новый элемент записывается в переменную `$t` (как-бы создается новый независимый элемент). Если вы хотите его изменять, нужно просто указать чтобы `$t` использовала ссылку на элемент массива, вот так:

```
foreach($test as &$t) {
    $t['test'] = 'add';
}
```

Тогда переменная `$t` будет ссылаться на элемент массива.